# c# mysql Stored Procedure Insert return value

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have this MySQL Stored Procedure which I use to Insert a record into the database. If I use `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteNonQuery()` command in C# to call this procedure, it is returning null for a successful insert. As per my knowledge the number of rows affected is inserted, which is not 0 in my case. Here's the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery)

How do I return the number of inserted records

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Contact_AddNew`(codeName varchar(50), fName varchar(50), lName varchar(50), contact varchar(50))
BEGIN
    SET @codeName = codeName;
    SET @fName = fName;
    SET @lName = lName;
    SET @contact = contact;
    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO Contacts (contactName, firstname, lastname, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @codeName, @fName, @lName, @contact;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Put a `RETURN ROW_COUNT();` after EXECUTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here..

A simple `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` will do..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count